# dyld[14823]: Library not loaded: @rpath/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode15

App is getting crashed as soon as it launches. I am getting this issue after updating my Mac OS to Sonoma 14.1 and Xcode Version 15.0.1 (15A507)

Here are full logs:

```
dyld[14823]: Library not loaded: @rpath/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier
  Referenced from: <ADA203B5-2D68-3EC4-8BB2-9F045B304FD5> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/NIM
  Reason: tried: '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EliteMatch-fqlxcslyborqtfdiyzxqgruzbfxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EliteMatch-fqlxcslyborqtfdiyzxqgruzbfxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/Frameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/Frameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EliteMatch-fqlxcslyborqtfdiyzxqgruzbfxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EliteMatch-fqlxcslyborqtfdiyzxqgruzbfxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/Frameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/Frameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS@rpath/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EliteMatch-fqlxcslyborqtfdiyzxqgruzbfxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EliteMatch-fqlxcslyborqtfdiyzxqgruzbfxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/Frameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/Frameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EliteMatch-fqlxcslyborqtfdiyzxqgruzbfxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EliteMatch-fqlxcslyborqtfdiyzxqgruzbfxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/Frameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9B3220A-587B-43E2-8555-6D45783B62E5/NIM.app/Frameworks/AANotifier.framework/AANotifier' (errno=2)
```

I have tried all ways mentioned on Internet. I have updated all pods and I am using   use_frameworks! in PodFile.